# Gradle Copy task with eachFile if clause works inconsistent, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

This is my task

```
task copyDeps(type: Copy) {
  from configurations.compile
  into 'build/lib'
  eachFile {
    if (it.relativePath.getFile(destinationDir).exists() && !it.relativePath.getFile(destinationDir).getName().contains("SNAPSHOT")) {
      it.exclude()
    }
  }
}
```

And it's supposed to download all the dependencies into the build/lib directory, except when there's already a file present with the same name, unless it's a snapshot.

But when all files are present, the snapshots don't get overwritten at all, which they should.

What's inconsistent is that when at least 1 file is missing (doesn't matter if it's a snapshot or not), then suddenly all the snapshots get overwritten, but not the non-snapshots.

So when at least one file is missing, the script works as intended, but when all files are present it just ignores half the expression of the if clause.

It's almost like it short circuits the "exists()" expression for the whole set of files.

Using gradlew which points to [gradle-5.0-bin.zip](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.0-bin.zip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's related to this: [gradle issue 4663](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4663)

The Copy task has a concept of inputs and outputs and when neither the inputs or the outputs have changed since the last run (same list of dependencies, same list of copied files in the target directory) the Copy task is considered UP-TO-DATE by gradle.

Found alternative:

```
task copyDeps() {
    project.copy {
        from configurations.compile
        into 'build/lib'
        eachFile {
            if (it.relativePath.getFile(project.file('build/lib')).exists() && !it.relativePath.getFile(project.file('build/lib')).getName().contains("SNAPSHOT")) {
                it.exclude()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Had to make some edits because this construct doesn't know a destinationDir. Also had to move the task to below the list of dependencies as it gave configuration errors I don't yet understand.